# Two completely different JSON files, need to display attributes of one

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have this `if` statement that chooses between two completely different JSON object (displayed below).

I need to display the result on the client side of things, I'm stomped tbh

My goal: I need to be able to display either the `error` part of the object, or the `count` part on the page. I'm sure there's something I'm missing,
My constraints is that I can't change anything within the JSON files.
Node.js and express related, my background is in basic Java though ;-;

Part of the code I have:

`Server side`

```
server.post(etc)
.
.
.
if(!textInputted.text){ 
        result = ({
            error: "Parameter text is missing."
    })} else{
        result = ({
            count: numOfWords
        })
    }
    console.log(result)
    res.json(result)
```

`Client side` (it's just this at the moment, I kept adding and removing)

```
fetch(etc)
.
.
.
.then (function(res){
              return res.json()
```

I could use more `if` statements to refine it and make it, I'm trying to learn and see other, cleaner solutions
EDIT:

Below are the two JSON objects from above. I'm using the line `res.json({result})` to return the object, however I don't know how to display the contents of the JSON objects without needing to know the contents beforehand.

```
{
            error: "Parameter text is missing."
    }
```

```
{
            count: numOfWords
        }
```

Comment: Please be more specific: What do you want to display? What do you get displayed instead?

Comment: It’s not bad practice to pass res.json in the if statements than reassigning it

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I want to display the contents of whatever JSON objects gets passed through `res.json({result})` without needing to know the contents of the JSON object (I've edited the original with some more context I hope it serves well)

Comment: What do you get displayed instead? `res.json(result)` should do what you want.